# OkHttp for Android: Option to NOT enforce Certificate/ public key pinning

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using Okhttp + Retrofit for networking in my SDK. I have a requirement to implement Certificate pinning but not enforce it. We just need to get the failure reports for pinning failure and would like the request to go through for now during the monitoring period.

TrustKit is another Certificate pinning library which provides this option to set enforce = false. With this, the request itself wouldn't fail but we can get the failure reports.

I do not see a way to achieve similar behavior using the Okhttp CertificatePinner. 
OkHttp would always fail the request with an exception if the Certificate pinning fails.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can achieve this behavior using the existing functionality?

Would have been easier if we could extend CertificatePinner class and override check() ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derived somewhat from you own answer on the issue tracker

```kotlin
package okhttp3

import javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException

fun main() {
  class LoggingCertificatePinnerInterceptor(val certificatePinner: CertificatePinner) : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
      val host = chain.request().url.host
      val certs = chain.connection()
          ?.handshake()?.peerCertificates.orEmpty()

      try {
        certificatePinner.check(host, certs)
      } catch (e: SSLPeerUnverifiedException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
      }
      return chain.proceed(chain.request())
    }
  }

  val certificatePinner = CertificatePinner.Builder()
      .add("graph.facebook.com", "sha256/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=")
      .build()
  val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .addNetworkInterceptor(LoggingCertificatePinnerInterceptor(certificatePinner))
      .build()

  val request = Request.Builder()
      .url("https://graph.facebook.com/robots.txt")
      .build()
  val response = client.newCall(request)
      .execute()

  println(response.code)
}
```

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate pinning failure!
  Peer certificate chain:
    sha256/KVFbweB8Ag9f08MZWU7m7cG83tpv8Ml39JpOHU3ESMg=: CN=*.facebook.com, O="Facebook, Inc.", L=Menlo Park, ST=California, C=US
    sha256/k2v657xBsOVe1PQRwOsHsw3bsGT2VzIqz5K+59sNQws=: CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
    sha256/WoiWRyIOVNa9ihaBciRSC7XHjliYS9VwUGOIud4PB18=: CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Pinned certificates for graph.facebook.com:
    sha256/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
    at okhttp3.CertificatePinner.check$okhttp(CertificatePinner.kt:199)
    at okhttp3.CertificatePinner.check(CertificatePinner.kt:149)
    at okhttp3.XxXKt$main$LoggingCertificatePinnerInterceptor.intercept(XxX.kt:13)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:82)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:197)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:148)
    at okhttp3.XxXKt.main(XxX.kt:32)
    at okhttp3.XxXKt.main(XxX.kt)
200
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the completed solution here from Github. Can you confirm when I call chain.connection()?.handshake()?.peerCertificates in my interceptor, would peerCertificates be already cleaned by Android OS and safe to use?
Because when I call certificatePinner.check(host, certs) in interceptor, it wouldn't be cleaned inside check() and used as it is, since certificateChainCleaner would be null inside CertificatePinner.

Comment: Another thing I would like to confirm is calling certificatePinner.check(host, certs) in above networkInterceptor is exactly same as RealConnection calling certificatePinner.check() in connectTls() method?
To make sure I am not missing anything by imitating the Cert pinning functionality in  interceptor.

Comment: Yes, they should be clean.  It should be the same results as applying the CertificatePinner.